# Regular Expression: interchange words by delimiter

Tags: regex

How can I interchange words by delimiter

Example:

> Surname, Name - filename.txt

I want this to be come

> Name Surname - filename.txt

I have file renamer which can rename file with regular expressions (A better rename in mac, and better file renamer on windows)

is it possible at all?

Comment: This is pretty vague. It's easy to do what you ask with sed, but I don't think what you ask is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching expression:

```
/^(.+), (.+) - (.+)$/
```

Replacement pattern:

```
$2 $1 - $3
```

Something along these lines should work, but this really depends on the capabilities and semantics of your regex engine and your specific input. No idea what Better Renamer allows you to do.

Comment: thnx! you're a live saver! now that's what I need =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "Surname, Name - filename.txt" | ruby -e 'print gets.gsub(/(\w+),\s+(\w+)(\s+-\s+\w+)/, "\\2 \\1 \\3")'
Name Surname  - filename.txt
```